# axios.post gives error on my VPS when sending post request locally to another app. Everything works fine on my local computer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, axios

So I have a Nginx configured to forward requests trough port 433 (SSL) to localhost:3000 where react is running, react shall in turn post requests to a Node.js app running on the same VPS (localhost:8080) to make a stripe payment.

Everything work fine so far. The frontend is rendering, SSL working.

But when the i run axios.post with the payment data from React it never reaches the Node (as far as my logs tell me).

I have CORS setup in node to accept a bunch of "localhost" variants and the actual domain itself.

Why is this not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have been poitning the React app to the Url of the api, not its local adress on my VPS sorry.